# How to add buttons to a scrollbar?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create an application that will allow a user automatically get the definitions of words. I'm doing this by creating a button of each word in a text dynamically and i want to add the buttons to a scrollbar.

I can get a scrollbar to appear but it does not scroll currently. And the buttons all appear in a vertical line.

```
from wiktionaryparser import WiktionaryParser
import json
import re
from tkinter import *
parser = WiktionaryParser()
parser.set_default_language('french')
root = Tk()
list_words = []
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filemenu = Menu(menu)
langmenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Import", menu=filemenu)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
def FromFile(): # Function for reading data from a text file
    global list_words
    root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("Text Files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
    UserFile = open(root.filename, 'r')
    UserString = UserFile.read()
    list_words = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", UserString)
    make_buttons()
filemenu.add_command(label="From File...", command=FromFile)
menu.add_cascade(label="Language", menu=langmenu)
# Menu that allows user to change the language 
def lang_fr():
    parser.set_default_language('french')
def lang_de():
    parser.set_default_language('german')
def lang_es():
    parser.set_default_language('spanish')
langmenu.add_command(label="French/Français", command=lang_fr)
langmenu.add_command(label="German/Deutsch", command=lang_de)
langmenu.add_command(label="Spanish/Espanol", command=lang_es)
# Gets the text from the button and returns the definiton 
def get_widget(widget):
        userInput = str(widget["text"])
        listy = parser.fetch(userInput)
        diction = listy[0]
        defin = diction["definitions"]
        defini = defin[0]
        definitus = defini["text"]
        definitus.pop(0)
        window = Toplevel(root)
        for definition in definitus:
            print(definition)





var = 0
#Function that makes the buttons 
def make_buttons():
    global list_words
    global var
    for word in list_words:
        btn = Button(root, text=word, bd=0)
        btn["command"] = lambda widget=btn:get_widget(widget)
        btn.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


    root.update()

root.mainloop()
```

Currently the output as stated has a scrollbar that doesn't work and all of the buttons are in a vertical line. I want a scroll bar and for the buttons to appear in a line by line form as if the user was reading normal text (like in a book).

Image of the output:
[image]

Comment: scrollbar doesn't know what you want to scroll

Comment: scrollbar is usefull with `Listbox` and `Text` (both with text) or `Canvas`. To scroll widgets (ie. `Buttons`) you will need `Canvas` with `Frame`. Search for "Scrolled Frame".

Comment: documentation for [scrollbar](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm)

Comment: my version of [Scrolled Frame](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/scrolled-frame-canvas)

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you mean by "add the buttons to a scrollbar"? For example, where would they appear?

Comment: Relevant [tkinter-and-hyperlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760561/tkinter-and-hyperlinks)